# Xcode delete the photos saved on the document app folder

Tags: iphone, flutter, xcode, photo, delete-file

Every time I build the app to run on the Iphone, all the photos that's saved on the data of the app just don't exist anymore. In the android everything are working just fine. I guess the new build delete every file saved on the app. Anyone can explain this to me?

I just play the app on the Iphone from the xcode and save a photo on the app document folder.